# Trigonometric formulas: $\frac{5cos(11/10t)+5cos(t+2/3*pi)}2 = 5\cos(\frac{21}{20}t+\frac13\pi)\cdot\cos(\frac1{20}t-\frac13\pi)$

Tags: trigonometry

Which trigonometric formulas are used for these problems?
[image]

Answer (score 1):

These come from the addition formulas $\cos(a+b)+\cos(a-b)=2\cos a\cos b$ and $\sin(a+b)+\sin(a-b)=2\sin(a)\cos(b)$

Comment: I guess that formula could be broken down in simpler formulas and sin(a)*sin(b) will cancel

Comment: Yes.  By the way, 'trigonometric' is more common in English than 'goniometric'

Answer (score 0):

HINT:

Use  $$\sin C+\sin D=2\sin\frac{C+D}2\cos\frac{C-D}2$$

and  $$\cos C+\cos D=2\cos\frac{C+D}2\cos\frac{C-D}2$$

Comment: @DinDan, Are you looking for this?